# ArgumentError (3 for 1) in Rails ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper when running rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, actionview, argument-error

I am in the process of upgrading our test suite to Capybara 2.1, and am running into the strangest issue when running the test suite.

### Using:

- ruby 1.9.3p392
- rails 3.2.12
- rspec 2.13.0
- capybara 2.1.0

When I run my tests for an entire suite (failing at once with descriptive formatting):

```
rspec spec/acceptance/non-webdriver-dependent/ --fail-fast -f d
```

The following error is thrown:

```
Failure/Error: within(".sidebar") do
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
```

When running with the `--backtrace` option, the following is reported:

```
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:51:in `concat'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `evaluate'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `block in xpath'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1..9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:150:in `map'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:150:in `xpath'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:214:in `css'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:85:in `find'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:70:in `find_css'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:152:in `block in resolve_query'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:77:in `synchronize'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:150:in `resolve_query'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:35:in `block in find'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:30:in `find'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:354:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:221:in `within'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
# ./spec/acceptance/non-webdriver-dependent/bronze/company_job_postings_index_sidebar_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `with_around_each_hooks'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
# /Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

However, when I run one test at a time, I have no problem whatsover. This is mind-boggling to me, and any insight anyone may have into this would be highly appreciated! **It is important to know this only occurs on the acceptance tests using the default driver rather than the selenium tests. Additionally, this error occurred only AFTER upgrading to capybara 2.1.0.**

Comment: Posted as [an issue on Capybara here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1060).
I seemed to have tracked it down to six files within the "/non-webdriver-dependent" directory structure that were including `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` for the sake of truncating expected content.

Comment: Is there anything in Capybara 2.1 that would not allow me to include `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` within specific spec files? I've since worked around this issue, but am curious about the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Like some people saying, the problem is `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`. In my case, I included it in a model. Fortunately I could remove it from the model and this error is cleared.